# how to handle element not interactable exception in selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, visual-studio-2019

**Web Element Code:**

```
<div class="form_field form_field--has_error sc-fBuWsC bNcPjv"
    <input id="temporaryEmail" autocomplete="false" name="temporaryEmail" class="sc-hzDkRC gHYxbL" value=""/>
    <label for="temporaryEmail" class="sc-jhAzac heNtmJ">
        Email Address 
    </label> 
</div>
```

**my Driver Code**

```
public IWebElement emailfield => Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='temporaryEmail']"));
```

If I just use: `emailfield.SendKeys(signUpCredentials.emailAddress);`
I get error Unhandled exception: `OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: 'element not interactable'`

If I use:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("$('document.querySelector(#temporaryEmail'))", emailfield); 
emailfield.SendKeys(signUpCredentials.emailAddress);
```

I get error Unhandled exception: `OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'javascript error: Unexpected token ')'
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.120)'`

Answer (score 0):

Try using below via javascript executor

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("document.querySelector('#temporaryEmail')", emailfield);
```